# Как избавиться от курсора мыши в приложении

Tags: c++, sfml

Работаю над игровым проектом используя библиотеку SFML. В игре нужно кликать мышью на разные предметы а курсор мыши блокирует спрайт игрового курсора.

Comment: нагуглил sf::Window::ShowMouseCursor(bool), это оно?

Comment: `void sf::Window::setMouseCursorVisible(bool visible)`, https://parg.co/Jq3 - оно?

Comment: Ага, большое спасибо =)

Answer (score 2):

`void sf::Window::setMouseCursorVisible(bool visible)`, документация [там](http://parg.co/Jq3)